# Overload constructors in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, class

I found a way to extend classes in VBScript, but are there any ways to pass in parameters or overload the constructor?  I am currently using an Init function to initialize the properties, but would like to be able to do this when I create the object.
This is my sample class:

```
Class Test
    Private strText

    Public Property Get Text
        Text = strText
    End Property

    Public Property Let Text(strIn)
        strText = strIn
    End Property

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()  
        Init
    End Sub  

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()   

    End Sub 

    Private Function Init
        strText = "Start Text"
    End Function    
End Class
```

And I create it

```
Set objTest = New Test
```

But would like to do something like this

```
Set objTest = New Test(strInitText)
```

Is this possible, or does the object have to be created and initialized in two setps?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just to alter slightly on svinto's method...

```
Class Test
  Private m_s
  Public Default Function Init(s)
    m_s = s
    Set Init = Me
  End Function
  Public Function Hello()
    Hello = m_s
  End Function
End Class

Dim o : Set o = (New Test)("hello world")
```

Is how I do it. Sadly no overloading though.

[edit]
Though if you really wanted to you could do something like this...

```
Class Test
    Private m_s
    Private m_i

    Public Default Function Init(parameters)
         Select Case UBound(parameters)
             Case 0
                Set Init = InitOneParam(parameters(0))
             Case 1
                Set Init = InitTwoParam(parameters(0), parameters(1))
             Else Case
                Set Init = Me
         End Select
    End Function

    Private Function InitOneParam(parameter1)
        If TypeName(parameter1) = "String" Then
            m_s = parameter1
        Else
            m_i = parameter1
        End If
        Set InitOneParam = Me
    End Function

    Private Function InitTwoParam(parameter1, parameter2)
        m_s = parameter1
        m_i = parameter2
        Set InitTwoParam = Me
    End Function
End Class
```

Which gives the constructors...

```
Test()
Test(string)
Test(integer)
Test(string, integer)
```

which you can call as:

```
Dim o : Set o = (New Test)(Array())
Dim o : Set o = (New Test)(Array("Hello World"))
Dim o : Set o = (New Test)(Array(1024))
Dim o : Set o = (New Test)(Array("Hello World", 1024))
```

Bit of a pain though.

Comment: It's 2011 and I both googled for this and enjoyed learning it. I like refactoring old VBScript the same way I like getting an old 486 running. I have no idea way.

Comment: You have to wrap the `(New Test)` in parentheses? You can't simply do, `New Test(Array())`? =[

Comment: I can't quickly test it but as far as I remember the parentheses are required. There are no class constructors so `New ClassName(arguments)` is not valid syntax in VBScript. The parentheses make it clear to the parser that you're applying the arguments to the result of `New ClassName`. Applying arguments to a object calls the function marked as default in the class definition.

Comment: Awesome.  There are a few minor errors: missing 'set' in interior functions, end function instead of end public, and end select instead of end case.

Comment: Parentheses are not required if explicitly calling `Init` (e.g. `Set o = New Test.Init("hello world")`. Unfortunately for the default function trick this does not work, so yes -- parentheses are required in this case.

Answer (score 7):

You can work around it by having your Init function returning the object itself...

```
Class Test
  Private m_s
  Public Function Init(s)
    m_s = s
    Set Init = Me
  End Function
  Public Function Hello()
    Hello = m_s
  End Function
End Class

Dim o
Set o = (New Test).Init("hello world")
Echo o.Hello
```

Comment: Why do I get an error for `Set o = (New Test).Init("hello world")` but not for `Set o = New Test : Set o=o.Init("hello world")` if I do all this in a QTP library, and put the `Set o=` statements into a method?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it in two steps. VB Script doesn't support overloading so you can't modify the default constructor with new parameters. Same goes for Vb6

Answer (score 1):

A bit hackish, for sure, but when I need varargs in calls, one of my parameters I pass in as an array, i.e.

```
Rem printf done poorly
sub printf(fmt, args)
  dim fp, vap:
  dim outs:
  dim fini:
      fini = 0:
      vap = 0:
  while (not fini)
    fp = index(fmt,"%"):
    if (not(isNull(fp))) then
        ' do something with %f, %s
        select case(fp)
        case 'c':
          outs = outs & charparse(args(vap)):
        case 's':
          outs = outs & args(vap):
        ' and so on.  Quite incomplete but you get the idea.
        end select
        vap = vap + 1
    end if
  wend
end sub

printf("%s %d\n",array("Hello World", 42)):
```